# How to divide encrypted lvm partition and prepare it to install 2nd OS next to UBUNTU

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption, lvm

I've installed Ubuntu with marked options :
- Erase disk and install Ubuntu
- Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security
- Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation
And I gave a full space of my SSD to Ubuntu.

Now I need to install one more OS on this SSD next to Ubuntu (Windows 10),
so here is my question :

How to divide encrypted (with ecryptfs) lvm partition to two parts and what are the steps after division to prepare fired space to be discoverable and usefull by Windows 10 installation wizard ?

Comment: Any idea how to do that without reinstalling Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install windows first...the Ubuntu multi boot menu works after you install other OS. I think your best option is to back up, install windows and then install ubuntu. Every time i read about this, it is always recommended to install windows firts. You dont have to do any special...ubuntu makes the partitions on the SSD and format the partition to install Ubuntu.

Sorry but i dont think installing win after ubuntu leads to better results.

Comment: Thanks for Your time :) Anyway.. Ubuntu is already installed.. configured and so on, i don't wont to touch it because i do not have an additional HDD that can fill my backup...

Comment: well too bad...good luck